# Display ALL posts with specific category, only returning one result so far- Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, categories

I am using 
 rails (5.1.4) 
and trying to show all posts tagged with a specific category. I am currently only able to return one post instead of every post with this category.

Post.rb

```
has_many :post_categories
has_many :categories, through: :post_categories

extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

def category_list
  categories.map(&:name)
end
```

Category.rb:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :post_categories
  has_many :posts, through: :post_categories

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
end
```

Category Controller:

```
def show
    @category = Category.find_by_name(params[:category])
    @posts = @category.posts
end
```

Category#show ERB: (where I am attempting to list every post with this category, but only getting one result, when I can physically look to see many posts with that same category)

```
 <% @posts.each do |post| %> 
   <h1 class="title"><%= link_to post.title, post_path(post) %></h1>
 <% end %>
```

From the Terminal:

```
Started GET "/category/Philadelphia%20maki" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-12-17 21:03:39 -0800
Processing by CategoriesController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"category"=>"Philadelphia maki"}
Category Load (5.6ms)  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."name" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["name", "Philadelphia maki"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Rendering categories/show.html.erb within layouts/dashboards
Post Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" INNER JOIN "post_categories" ON "posts"."id" = "post_categories"."post_id" WHERE "post_categories"."category_id" = $1  [["category_id", 15]]
```

Routes:

```
category GET|POST /category/:category(.:format) categories#show
```

Posts#show ERB:

```
<ul class="category-list">
    <% @post.category_list.map.each do |category|  %></p>
      <li itemprop="genre" class="category-list-item"> <%= link_to "#{category}", category_path(category) %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
```

Comment: Check `PostCategory.where(category_id: 15).count`

Comment: I'm getting a count of one, but I'm physically seeing the tag on multiple posts. Do I have something set up wrong in the models?

Comment: Getting a count of 1 means acc to your database, you have only 1 post for that category.

Comment: You will need to show us the code that displays the tags for a post for debugging it further.

Comment: Random? but this method `category_list` in `Post` does not look like returning random category names.

Comment: maybe I am not understanding.

Comment: Check this too: `Category.where(name: 'Philadelphia maki').count`. May be you have multiple categories with same name.

Comment: count: 4! this is the problem!

Comment: Yes.... You need to have a validation in `Category` model for uniqueness of name. That will prevent such error from happening in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For users visiting this page,

**Problem**

User was seeing multiple posts with the same category name on a different page but when fetching posts of that category, it was returning only 1 post.

**Cause**

There were multiple `Category` records in the database with the same name.

**Solution**

Add a validation to model `Category`:

```
validates :name, uniqueness: true, allow_blank: true
```